# Client side routing using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm doing some experimenting in using pure JS/jQuery to handle client-side logic (rather than a framework, like Angular).  The problem I'm running into right now is how to log a user in.

Here is my `login.hbs` file:

```
<div align="center">
<h2 class="page-header">Account Login</h2>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{!-- Username --}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width: 20%">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{!-- Password --}}
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 20%">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

This submit request goes to a JS file: `login.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    login = () => {     
        var username = $("[name='username']").val()
        var password = $("[name='password']").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: '/login',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Success:')
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Error:")
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

On the server side, I'm accepting this `PUT` request in `index.js`:

```
router.put('/login', function(req, res) {
    // Password is not encrypted here
    console.log('req.body')
    console.log(req.body)

    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
        // Password is encrypted here
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('user')
        console.log(user)

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET)
                return res.status(200).send({ user: user, token: token })
            } else {
                return res.status(401).send({error: "Something is wrong."})
            }
        })
    })
})
```

The current flow is: a user enters their credentials, and those credentials get returned to the `success` method in my `ajax` request.  The credentials show up in the browser's console (confirming that the server and client are communicating).  The question is, how do I route this request to the profile page (or any other page, for that matter)?  That is, the user is at `http://localhost:3000/login`, and after successfully logging in, they are routed to `http://localhost:3000/profile`, for example, where their personal profile information appears.  I'd love to learn both ways of doing this type of routing (server-side and client-side).  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you your try `window.location`?

Comment: Ok, that worked!  Thanks!  I think I tried `window.location.href` earlier, but it wasn't working.  I hand-coded the full URL, `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/profile'`, and it worked.  Do you happen to know if it's best practice to handle routing in the server, or in the client?  When a user logs in, I'm sending back all of their user info (name, email, and so forth) from the server.  It looks like with `window.location.href`, I'd have to include that information as URL parameters, like 'http://localhost:3000/profile?username=farid` or something.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You concerns are a large part of the definition of client side routing. Client side routing is a key feature of single page applications. Generally, however, they do not actually change pages, they simple swap different views in and out. As for credentials, you generally query for them on load or login.

Comment: For client side routing to work well, you want to replace only part of the page, then you only have to request credentials on the initial load. Login can return a server-side-validated token that you can save in local storage.

Comment: That's an excellent point: using local storage.  Once the info is sent back from the server, I can store all of it in a cookie, and then use that info, client side, without having to make any more requests to the server.  Is that correct?  That way, I don't need to pass any info as URL parameters, like `window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/profile/' + response.user.username`.  That method works, but then the user's username is exposed in the URL, which may not be ideal.  It sounds like I should be able to save it as a cookie in the browser, which makes it accessible from any URL.

Comment: Security is a very tricky topic. I definitely agree that the data should not be in the URL but using window.location was just a direct way of performing the desired action. I would look into partial page replacement as using different physical pages for each screen will lead to bad UX. Also, local storage is **not** secure.

Comment: Partials is a great idea.  I could use handlebars for that, but I had difficulty getting that to work with express (I may need to post another question for that problem).  I read different opinions regarding local storage, which was why I went with cookies. You've helped so much!  I'm starting to feel more confident in using client-side routing (it's one of the reasons I dropped Angular: I just couldn't get it to work).

Comment: I thought this was just a proof of concept actually. I would use an existing framework. Getting all of this to work is a massive undertaking. I'm glad my remarks were useful to you though :) If you don't like Angular there are many other frameworks like Aurelia, React, Ember, and more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143637/discussion-between-farid-and-aluan-haddad).